# DOM element with background image to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, svg

I have to make a library that takes a thumbnail of a website.

I convert the HTML and styles into serialized XML data with Javascript:

```
serialized = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( html );
```

After that I create string data from the serialized string:

```
var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '">' +
'<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">'
+ serialized +
'</foreignObject>' +
'</svg>';
```

After I print this data on the canvas element, I have seen that everything works fine except the background images of divs.

How can I convert a DOM element that contains a `background-image` property to work with canvas?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: Need more details and code ? What is serialized ? background images?

Comment: element is serialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Convert url to base64 and works fine.